# Extract word or digit from command or PowerShell output

Tags: powershell, command-line

Were in the process of creating a large number of scripts to gather data from PCs. I need some help with extracting the relevant data using the "simplest" method. I just need a method/concept/idea and we’ll apply to the rest. Here are 3 examples

1. Ping Avg MS response: The output of a ping will display results like this: “Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 8ms, Average = **4**ms”. I would need to extract the Avg number w/o the “ms” and redirect the output to a file (>PingAvg.txt). The end result is for the output file to only have a “**4**” in the file.
2. WMI AV Output: Ill the run a “Get-WmiObject” PowerShell such as the one below. I would need to extract just the name (displayName) or just the state, and redirect the output to a file (>AvStats.txt). The end results is for the output file to only contain the name of the AV product “**Windows Defender**” or only the state “**393472**”

```html
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\SecurityCenter2 -Query "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, Scope, Path, Options, ClassPath, Properties, SystemProperties, QualifiersSite, Container | Format-List -Property [a-z]

displayName              : Windows Defender
instanceGuid             : {D68DDC3A-831F-4fae-9E44-DA132C1ACF46}
pathToSignedProductExe   : %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe
pathToSignedReportingExe : %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MsMpeng.exe
productState             : 393472
timestamp                : Mon, 23 Oct 2017 14:12:56 GMT
```

3. Get Last date of patching: The powershell command and output would look like the output showing below. I would like to get just the data and redirect the output to a file (>LastPatch.txt). The output file should only contain the date “**9/25/2018**”

PS C:> (get-hotfix | sort installedon)[-1] | Select-Object InstalledOn

InstalledOn

9/25/2018 12:00:00 AM

Comment: That's quite basic stuff, what have you tried so far? => `Get-Help Select-Object` see -ExpandProperty, or enclose the command in parentheses and append the property with a dot.

Comment: As @LotPings already said: try to get the properties you want with a dot like so: `($conn.ResponseTime | Measure-Object -Average).Average` where `$conn` contains the result of your `Test-Connection` or try `(Get-HotFix).InstalledOn` to get the Hotfix-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for step 1:

```
(((ping localhost | Select-String "Average") -split "Average = ")[1] -split "ms")[0] | out-file PingAvg.txt
```

Step 2:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\SecurityCenter2 -Query "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct" | Select-Object displayName | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string).trim() | out-file AvStats.txt
```

OR for product state

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\SecurityCenter2 -Query "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct" | Select-Object productState | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string).trim() | out-file AvStats.txt
```

Step 3:

```
((get-hotfix | sort installedon)[-1] | Select-Object InstalledOn | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string).trim() | out-file LastPatch.txt
```

Please share your feedback. If it helps then make sure to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks LT! This is exactly what i was looking for, and provided us with some great concepts and food for thought. Quick Question on the Get-Hotfix command. What if we wanted for the hotfix date to only contain the date w/o the time. Can you specify a time format and/or split?

Comment: Just curious : why are you using ping and parse the textdata instead of using the built in Test-Connection command which returns an object?

Comment: Bluuf, i could, as Razorfen suggested. I was thinking it might be easier to get the data with a single command Vs creating a variable ($conn) and then evaluate the variable. Nonetheless, as you could see, im no expert at this. I even managed to get my question down-voted...

Comment: Hi @Joe. This is what you can do to just get the date. Split using space:


`(((get-hotfix | sort installedon)[-1] | Select-Object InstalledOn | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string).trim() -split ' ')[0]`



Please upvote and don't forget to mark as the answer.

Comment: Thanks LT. Works perfect! One last question if i may. The "productState" query isnt trimming the leading empty space if it returns two lines. So ill have in line 1 "331776" on the far right of the screen (trimmed correctly), and then line 2 "393472" on the far left side of the screen

Comment: try this 
    ((Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\SecurityCenter2 -Query "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusPr
oduct" | Select-Object productState | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string) -split "`n").trim()